# Test zip file upload using HTTP PUT method using the curl

Tags: curl, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, web-api-testing

I am trying to upload the zip file to a folder using the put method. Below is my put method which accepts the zip file:

```
 [HttpPut("ImportFile")]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddFileToFolder(IFormFile file)
    {
        
        string fileExtension;

        if (file == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

         //The helper method that upload file to folder "C:\test" folder
         await Helper.UploadFile(file);
       


        return Ok();
    }
}
```

When I test this using the postman it is working fine. But when I test it using the curl like below:

```
C:\test> curl --insecure PUT -T "C:\test\Test_1.zip" "https://localhost:7098/TestController/ImportFile"
```

I get the error of "Could not resolve host: PUT"

I also get error when I try used the below command with curl:

curl --insecure https://localhost:7098/TestController/ImportFile --upload-file "C:/test/Test_1.zip"
In this case I get these errors:

{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-d2c03ced5ba843a959c42a6fdb049122-c32240f288eac9b8-00","errors":{"file":["The file field is required."]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using -F curl options solve my issue:

```
curl --insecure -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F file=@/C:/test/Test_1.zip" localhost:7098/TestController/ImportFile"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could click the circle in the picture and you could see the curl with postman
[image: curl]

Codes in api controller:

```
[HttpPut("ImportFile")]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public IActionResult upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            var a = HttpContext.Request;
            return Ok();
        }
```

[image]

Curl:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'https://localhost:44323/WeatherForecast/ImportFile' \
--form 'file=@"/C:/Users/ruikaif/Desktop/x.xml.txt"'
```

Comment: I try the curl command get from post man: curl --location --request PUT 'https://localhost:7098/TestController/ImportFile' --form 'file=@"/C:/test/Test_1.zip"' . This time I get the error of "curl: (26) Failed to open/read local data from file/application"

Comment: I am still facing the same issue of Failed to open/read local data from file application. I would really appreciate it if anyone could share the solution of the issue. Thanks

Comment: By using -F options solve my issue: "curl --insecure -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file=@/C:/test/Test.zip" https://localhost:7098/TestController/ImportFile"